# Problems in applying pattern at same time to restrict range and specific characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I need to apply pattern to one of my field in angularjs code. It needs to fulfill following conditions:

> The value must be between 1 - 50 characters long. Name can contain only >letters, numbers, periods, hyphens, and underscores. Name must start and end >with a letter or number.
>
> I have tried this pattern
>   /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{0,48}[a-zA-Z0-9]$/
>
> It works well for all other conditions except it accepts atleast two >characters.

I have tried many variations, but either range is compromised, or I face problem in restricting hyphens and underscores at start. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{0,48}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/` this I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[\w.-]{0,48}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Matches start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - Starts matching with an alphabet or digit
- `(?:` - Start of non-grouping pattern
- `[\w.-]{0,48}[a-zA-Z0-9]` - What next matches can be alphabets, digits, periods, underscore and hyphen but the last character should be an alphabet or digit
- `)?` - Non-group pattern closed and `?` makes it optional so as to allow only one character as a valid variable
- `$` - End of string

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f4YkWz/1)** (For making demo easier to play with strings, I have reduced the length condition to 1-5 instead of 1-50 as asked in question)